# Xamarin binding byte[] or NSObject[]

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to bind the following function from an Objective-C library in Xamarin.

```
/*!
 *  This function writes data to the device.
 *
 *  @param writeBuffer Pointer to a byte buffer containing the write data.
 *  @param offset      Amount of data that was already written.
 *  @param size        Amount of data left to write.
 *
 *  @return Amount of data written.
 *
 *  @note Throws PortException on failure.
 */
- (u_int32_t)writePort:(u_int8_t const *)writeBuffer :(u_int32_t)offSet :(u_int32_t)size;
```

I can't work out what the data type should be for writeBuffer.

```
    [Export ("writePort:::")]
    Int32 WritePort (Byte[] writeBuffer, int offSet, int size);
```

I have tried Byte[] (shown above) but I get the following error:

```
/Projects/StarIOBinding/StarIOBinding/obj/Debug/ios/StarIO/SMPort.g.cs(34,34): Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.FromNSObjects(params MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject[])' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (StarIOBinding)
```

I then tried:

```
    [Export ("writePort:::")]
    Int32 WritePort (NSObject[] writeBuffer, int offSet, int size);
```

Which then compiles - but when running the command, I'm not getting the expected result. I am sending it a Byte[] wrapped up in an NSObject. Is NSObject the correct parameter and where am I going wrong?

**Edit:** When using IntPtr, I'm still getting no output. Can I just confirm I'm doing it correctly? My binding:

```
    [Export ("writePort:::")]
    Int32 WritePort (IntPtr writeBuffer, int offSet, int size);
```

And when I'm calling it:

```
    IntPtr test = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myByteArray.Length);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(myByteArray, 0, test, myByteArray.Length);
    SMPort devPort = SMPort.GetPort ("TCP:10.0.1.4", "", 5);
    int count = devPort.WritePort (test, 0, myByteArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `IntPtr` in the bindings and use the `Marshal` class to copy bytes back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated my question, am I now calling it correctly?

Comment: It's a binding for a receipt printer. I'm not getting any errors thrown now, but no receipt is being printed! :( I'm guessing it must be to do with the way I'm sending my byte array to the printer - but my understanding of Objective-C are making it really hard to understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What's the 'count' variable after you've written to the port?

Comment: 14951, which is the same as my byte array length.

Comment: That means the data is sent to the printer, could it be the wrong data? Did you compare the exact byte contents with an Objective-C sample?

Comment: Yes, it appears the printer needs a specific set of commands. I've ended up creating a new Objective-C library which I knew worked, then wrapping that in another binding where I can just send it the UIImage that I wish to print and all the logic is done in Objective-C. Seems to do the trick. Thanks for your help.